# Not able to do re parenting in this question. If an opportunity is removed from an account then it should be removed from the Account lookup field

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

issue in re parenting, In this question i have to find the largest opportunity by amount and put into the Account lookup field which is working but when i am changing the account of an opportunity then it remains in the account look up field. can someone please correct it, if i am wrong

```
public class TopOpportunityClass{
    public static boolean flag = true;
    public static void onTopOpportunity(List<Opportunity> opport){
        if(flag==true){
            List<Opportunity> uptOpp = new List<Opportunity>();

            Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
            for(Opportunity opp : opport){
                if(opp.AccountId != null){
                    accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
                }
            }

            Map<Id, List<Opportunity>> accOpportMap = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();
            List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
            for(Opportunity obj : [SELECT id,name, amount,accountId
                                   FROM Opportunity
                                   WHERE accountId IN :accIds ORDER BY amount DESC nulls last]){

                                       List<Opportunity> oppList;
                                       if(accOpportMap.containsKey(obj.accountId)){
                                           oppList = accOpportMap.get(obj.accountId);
                                       }else{
                                           oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
                                       }
                                       oppList.add(obj);
                                       accOpportMap.put(obj.accountId, oppList);
                                   }
            for(Id accId : accOpportMap.keySet()){
                if(accOpportMap.get(accId).size() > 1 ){
                    opportunity opp1 = new opportunity(id = accOpportMap.get(accId)[1].id , isTopOpportunityCheck__c = false);
                    uptOpp.add(opp1);
                    accUpdateList.add(new Account(id = accId, isTopOpportunity__c = accOpportMap.get(accId)[0].id));
                    opportunity opp = new opportunity(id = accOpportMap.get(accId)[0].id , isTopOpportunityCheck__c = true);
                    uptOpp.add(opp);

                }else if(accOpportMap.get(accId).size() == 1 ){
                    accUpdateList.add(new Account(id = accId, isTopOpportunity__c = accOpportMap.get(accId)[0].id));
                    opportunity opp = new opportunity(id = accOpportMap.get(accId)[0].id , isTopOpportunityCheck__c = true);
                    uptOpp.add(opp);


                }else if(accOpportMap.get(accId).size() == 0){
                    accUpdateList.add(new Account(isTopOpportunity__c = NULL, id = NULL));
                }
                flag = false;
            }
            if(!accUpdateList.isEmpty()){
                update accUpdateList;
                update uptOpp;
            }
        }
    }
}
//trigger
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update){
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        TopOpportunityClass.onTopOpportunity(Trigger.new);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running `after update`, so you're getting the *new* values in each sObject. If you want to affect the *old* Account assigned to some reparented Opportunity, you need to also look at the value in `Trigger.old` or `Trigger.oldMap`.

The way to do this would be to add a check here:

```
        for(Opportunity opp : opport){
            if(opp.AccountId != null){
                accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
            }
        }
```

to find a reparented Opportunity (`opp.AccountId != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).AccountId`) and affect that Account as well.

There's a separate issue further below: this logical branch is clearly wrong.

```
            }else if(accOpportMap.get(accId).size() == 0){
                accUpdateList.add(new Account(isTopOpportunity__c = NULL, id = NULL));
            }
```

You can't `update` an `Account` whose `Id` is `null`, and that will produce an exception.

You also need to reset `flag` to `true` after performing updates, or your trigger will have some very confusing and difficult-to-debug edge cases when multiple DML operations are performed in a single transaction.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for ur answer, i have one more question regarding this. Can you please check this statement "for(Id accId : accOpportMap.keySet())" below all the code is not bulkified, can you please tell me how would i do that.